# Charge on capacitors after connecting them

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance

In Figure 1, how can we be sure that after the switch is closed, in each capacitor, the plates would carry an equal positive and negative charge? Why can't it be the case that say in the capacitor in the middle, the left plate carry a certain amount of positive charge and the right plate carry an different amount of negative charge?

Would it be different in Figure 2? (I've flipped the signs on the middle capacitor?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your initial conditions are. Are the capacitors initially neutral? If not, and the plates can start out different, then they can end up different. If the starting point is that each capacitor has equal and opposite q on each plate, then you should be able to show that the final solution has the same condition. It is a simple matter of finding electrostatic equilibrium using a $E = \sigma/2\epsilon$ equation.

I would understand your $C_{i}$, $V_{i}$ initial condition to mean that there is a known $\pm Q_{i}$ on each plate given by the capacitance formula.

The outcome definitely depends on how they are connected. The one on the left will definitely discharge, the one on the right may not. If the starting condition is that the plates have equal and opposite charge, though, charge conservation and the field equation above will show that they do in equilibrium. There will be electrostatic equilibrium when there is zero field net field in the wire, and the capacitor will put out net field based on the difference in $\sigma$ from above (and therefore $Q$).

This all assumes that the capacitance of the wire can be neglected. In reality, electrostatic problems are dependent upon the geometry, so assuming that the effect of the capacitor dominates over any trace charges that build up along the wire surface is a simplifying assumption.

EDIT:

To answer your comment, as you know the net field in a capacitor is $E = \sigma/\epsilon$. When you have the factor of two in the denominator or not is always confusing to try to memorize, but in any given problem you can find the estimated field from the Gauss Law. Basically, you can think of the case of a parallel plate capacitor as the fields of the plates adding in between the plates (getting rid of the factor of 2 in the denominator) and cancelling outside of the plates, due to the two $\sigma$ (for each plate) being the same. This is the assumption and analysis implicit in the $C = A\epsilon/d$ capacitance equation. It is due to the areas being the same and the definition of capacitance as the voltage developed between two conductors of a given geometry when equal and opposite charge is placed on them. This is the definition of capacitance (specifically $C = Q/V$) and is a function of geometry (and intervening medium properties) only.

If the plates have different amounts of charge on them, the net field (near the plate centers of course) can be found the same way. In this case, the interior field would not have a single value of $\sigma$ with the over two going away, and the exterior field will not exactly cancel. Please let me know if you don't understand that last part (try drawing a picture and adding or subtracting the fields with different values of $\sigma$ for each plate).

Since the exterior field does not exactly cancel, there is a tendency for current to flow in the wire. So, without doing an exact geometric electrostatic analysis, we can just use that net field as the field in the wire.

In reality, electrostatics is a geometrical problem, so you would have to define capacitor geometries as well as the wire (wire diameter and the curve path it follows). The same condition I just described is required *everywhere in a conductor* in this form of analysis. If you remember, the exact requirement is that the field be perpendicular to the conductor surface and the surface charge density be the amount to cancel that field by the $E = \sigma/2\epsilon$ equation. This is a difficult problem, even if the geometry is defined (it isn't here). So I assume the assumption you are supposed to make is you use the parallel plate field for each half of the capacitor even when the Qs are not the same.

I will point out that it looks to me like it is possible to set up static equilibrium with different amounts of charge on each plate of a single capacitor. However, your C, V pairs are only defined for equal charges (by $C = Q/V$), so assuming that is supposed to be the initial condition, your initial condition probably intends for them to start out equal and opposite. I have not done an exact analysis, but I am having a hard time thinking of a way to get them to end up in such a way that two plates of the same capacitor have different charges.

Comment: Sorry, I should've stated that. The values quoted above each capacitor are the initial conditions.
But I don't know how to use the equation for equation for electric field due a plate (E=σ/2ϵ) here. I do know that the field between the plates is E=σ/ϵ. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I added an addendum to answer this. Please let me know if that makes sense or not.

Comment: Thank you for writing this. Yes, understand it conceptually how to go about it, sort of.
I was thinking it would be simpler..... like apply law of conversation of charge, and Kirchhoff's voltage law and I'd arrive at the result. Doesn't look like that's the case :)
But this is at the high school level, so I guess I'd just stipulate that the charges after the key is closed will be the same on the two plates of each capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

The charge on series capacitors is indeterminate. One thing you can say is that after the switch is thrown, $V_1+V_2+V_3=0$ (a consequence of Kirchhoff's voltage law), but they may not individually be zero. You can also say that the event of throwing the switch changes each capacitor's charge by the same amount (a consequence of Kirchoff's current law).

In real life, we often add [balance resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266085/balancing-resistor-values-for-series-capacitors) to series capacitors to insure that the charge stays under control.